# Expectation of a Geometric Brownian Motion at an independent random time

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, stopping-times

Let $W_t$ be a Brownian motion.

I'm interested in the expectation
$$ \mathbb{E} \left[ \exp \left\{ \sigma W_\tau \right\} \right] $$
where $\tau$ is a random time independent of $W_t$.

Here's my attempt:
$$
\mathbb{E} \left[ \exp \left\{ \sigma W_\tau \right\} \right] 
= \mathbb{E} \left[ \exp \left\{ \sigma \sqrt{\tau} Z \right\} \right] 
$$
where $Z$ is a standard normal independent of $\tau$.

Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E} \left[ \exp \left\{ \sigma \sqrt{\tau} Z \right\} \right] 
&= \mathbb{E} \left[ \mathbb{E} \left[  \exp \left\{ \sigma \sqrt{\tau} Z \right\} \big| \tau \right] \right] \\
&= \mathbb{E} \left[ \exp \left\{ \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \tau \right\} \right] \\
\end{aligned}
$$
which I can then get from the Laplace transform of $\tau$.

Is this argument correct?

Comment: It is correct. You could have also used the expectation of the log-normal law or the moment-generating function of the normal law.